# Artifactory retention of artifacts. Jenkins artifactory plugin

Tags: artifactory

We use retention of artifact in build info.

```
 def buildInfo = server.upload(uploadSpec)
 buildInfo.retention maxDays: 5, doNotDiscardBuilds: Eval.me(env.param), deleteBuildArtifacts: true
```

Artifact deploys to snapshot repository (uploadSpec contains link to snapshot repository), but then promotes to the next repositories. Here is the question: if we turn on retention function it will have influence on snapshot repository only or all next promoted repositories also will be cleaned with retention function after 5 days?